# Storing list of same type type as entity

Tags: android, android-room, dao

Lets suppose I have an entity "Article" and it may have a list of Articles inside it received from the api. The question is how to save this list that has the same type as the entity using room.

I am saving them as embedded using type converters but nothing is saved

```
    @Entity(tableName = "articles")
public class Article {
   @Embedded
    @TypeConverters(ArticleTypeConverter.class)
    @SerializedName("relatedArticles")
    @Expose
    private ArrayList<Article> relatedArticles = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, `Article` class should be an object that mimics the structure of the article you're getting from the server. In addition, you will need a separate class that holds a `List` of those `Article` instances.

```
    public class Article {
    //.....
           private String title;
           private String author;
    //.....
    }
```

and here's the class you need to save

```
@Entity(tableName = "articles")
public class Articles {
     //.....
     @SerializedName("relatedArticles")
     public List<Article> relatedArticles;
     //.....
}
```

*NOTE* I added the `Article` class w/ fields I imagined it would have, but for it to work it'd need to match names/types of fields that your server returns.